# Data-centric web application design book/article recommendations

Tags: user-interface, web-applications, usability

I am designing a web application that deals with lots of data. I find it difficult to present this data in a usable, intuitive way. The data has to be sortable/searchable, and the relationships between the data should be obvious (records can have "child items").

Are there any books that specifically deal with this? I am not looking for a general web design book or a general usability book. However, if there are general books that are deal with this topic especially well, please do mention them.

Comment: Did you end up with anything interesting here?

Answer (score 1):

The books "The Visual Display of Quantitative Information" or "Envisioning Information"
by Edward R. Tufte could be helpful.

They don't deal with web applications, but if I've read your question correctly you problem is more of a general nature and not specifically attached to web application development.